# Ionic: Share specific page via social media

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, ionic3, socialshare

I'm developing an application of list and detail of peoples. The main page is a list of users. Each user have with many sections: personal information, goals, etc. How to share specific page of a user via WhatsApp, SMS, etc so that when it is pressed it directs it to the corresponding profile and not to the main listing of the app?. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I know how to share the profile, but I do not know how to notify the application that should be opened in a certain user profile.

Comment: How to warn the application that it is not a normal start and configure a certain page? Also verifying that the application is installed on the device of the person who received the link

Answer (score 1):

Use plugin social sharing i think

[Social sharing](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/social-sharing/)

Comment: Yes, I use that, but I do not know how to notify the application that should be opened in a certain user profile like instagram sharing

Comment: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin#using-the-share-sheet

Comment: So you mean that when click share. It goes to the intagram profile of the user?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use two plugins, [Deeplinks](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/deeplinks/) and [SocialSharing](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/social-sharing).
The first one is to open the app into a specific page or content, the second one to give your user the ability to share content from your app, links in your case.

[Here is a simple tutorial](https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/ionic2-app-with-socialsharing-and-deeplinking) that makes use of the two plugins which allow users to share links to specific content in the app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use social sharing plugin and dynamic link (firebase or branch.io) as of the time of answering.